# Understanding Dual Transformations and reasoning behind definition

Tags: linear-algebra

In Linear Algebra working with Dual space and dual transformations I've come along this very basic definition of the dual transformations:

> Suppose:
>
> $T^*$ is a dual transformations from $W^*\to V^*$
>    $T$ is a linear transformation from $V\to W$
>    $u$ is a linear functional which belongs to $W^*$
>    $v$ is a vector which belongs to $V$
>   
>    Then the following applies:
>      $$ (T^*u)(v)  = u(Tv) $$

Why is the dual transformation defined this way? (I know this is a very problematic question, but please any intuition will be very helpful)

Comment: $T^*$ goes from $W^*$ to $V^*$ if $T:V\to W$.

Comment: Usually, if $T: V\rightarrow W$, then $T*:W^{*}\rightarrow V^{*}$, with $T^{*}(\psi)(v)=\psi(T(v))$. You need to invert the arrow in the definition of $T^{*}$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the special case of matrix algebra, this turns out to be fairly obvious.

In this setting, one usually writes vectors as $n \times 1$ matrices ("column vectors"), and linear functionals as $1 \times n$ matrices ("row vectors").

If we have a matrix $A$ with suitable dimensions, then "multiplication on the left" results in a linear transformation (call it $T$): i.e. $T(v) = Av$. The dual transformation is "multiplication on the right". That is, $T^*(u) = uA$. So your identity is merely

$$ (uA)v = u(Av) $$

Comment: Thanks for the response, while this does give a good intuition, I don't completely understand why T* is denoted by A and so is T. Why is it so that both of them have the same vectors in their matrix in the first place?

Comment: @vondip: Try turning the question around: we know for matrices it's useful to be able to multiply on the left *and* on the right. So how do you translate that to the abstract setting? The value of $(uA)$ at $v$ should be the value of $u$ at $Av$. The notation $T^*(u)$ is, in some sense, an artifact of using the convention that linear transformations are always written on the left. If we didn't adopt that convention, we could write $(u)T$ or even just $uT$ rather than writing $T^*(u)$. Of course, $u \circ T$ makes sense either way, and $T^*(u)$ does equal $u \circ T$...

Comment: And sometimes, we need to think of the space of linear functionals as a vector space in its own right, rather than as a space of functionals -- so that's another setting where we need notation to reflect the fact we've "transposed" how $T$ acts on things. One particular case of this sort of thing is when we have an inner product on $V$, and we use it to convert elements of $V$ into elements of $V^*$ instead.

Comment: Thank you very much Hurkyl, this is an excellent answer that helped me understand this vague topic.

Answer (score 1):

Given a map $T: V \to W$ where $V, W$ are $K$ vector spaces.  We define the transpose or (dual transformation) $T^* :  W^* \to V^*$ of $T$ by $T^*(f) = f \circ T$.   I think it's defined this way, because it's the most natural way to associate to each linear map a new map on the corresponding dual spaces.

There's a reason this assignment is called the transpose. If $V$ is finite dimensional, any basis $\beta = \{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ of $V$, gives rise to $n$ linear functionals $v^*_i : V \to K$ defined by $v^*_i(w) = a_i$ where $a_i$ is the $i$'th component of $[w]_B$. The collection $B^* = \{v^*_i : 1 \le i \le n\}$ is linearly independent and spans $V^*$, and therefore forms a basis which we call the dual basis of $\beta$.  Fix ordered bases $\beta$ and $\gamma$ of $V$ and W, respectively.  Assuming $W$ is finite dimensional, if $T: V \to W$ is linear map, we have a matrix representation of $T$ denoted $[T]_\beta^ \gamma$.  It's fairly straightforward to prove that

$$[T^*]_{\gamma^*} ^{\beta^*} = ([T]_\beta^ \gamma)^t$$

where by $( \cdots )^t$ I mean the transpose of a matrix.

Some properties of taking the dual:

The assignment $V \mapsto V^*, T \mapsto T^*$ is what's called a contravariant functor (i.e. a functor that reverses composition and morphisms (linear maps)) on $\mathbf{Vect}_K$ the category of $K$ vector spaces.

If $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional, $T \mapsto T^*$ is an injective linear map from $\operatorname{Hom}_K(V, W)$ to $\operatorname{Hom}_K(W^*, V^*)$ and hence an isomorphism since both spaces have dimesion $\dim V \dim W$.